# Is there a better way to define this boolean variable?

Tags: python, oop, boolean

Suppose I have a some config file that specifies whether or not I get none, one of all of something. That is if `get_one_of_this` is `True`, then I get one of something. If it is `False` then I get none of it. However, I also want a boolean to specify that I get all of something, so I denote this as `get_all_of_this`. The issue is that the two are in a way redundant, ie. if `get_one_of_this` is `False`, then so should `get_all_of_this`. Is there a better way to do this?

```
@dataclass
class SomeConfig:
  get_one_of_this: bool
  get_all_of_this: bool
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate get_all_of_this value in conjunction with get_one_of_this.

```
get_all_of_this = get_one_of_this and config.get_all_of_this
```

However I would use an [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) to get it done by defining an enum for 3 states.

```
>>> class State(Enum):
...     NONE = 0
...     ONE = 1
...     ALL = 2
... 
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would look into [enumerations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) if I were you. You could enumerate `none, one, all` and use that because boolean values are really only supposed to be used when there are 2 discrete states, while enumerations can be used for an arbitrary number of discrete states.

```
class Quantity(Enum):
    NONE = 0
    ONE = 1
    ALL = 2
```